# I am trying to download miniconda but I am getting an error saying that the destination has a special character

Tags: miniconda

I am trying to download miniconda but I am getting an error saying that the destination has a special character.

I am getting an error message and cannot install the application.

I tried to change destination but nothing changed. How can I install this application?

I read that I should disable antivirus but not sure how to do that.

Comment: This, as written, does not sound like a programming problem as defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please include more detail about your OS and how you are trying to download.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.